# Ruby - Find element not in common for two arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, unique

I've been thinking about a following problem - there are two arrays, and I need to find elements not common for them both, for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,4]
```

And the expected answer is `[3]`.

So far I've been doing it like this:

```
a.select { |elem| !b.include?(elem) }
```

But it gives me `O(N ** 2)` time complexity. I'm sure it can be done faster ;)

Also, I've been thinking about getting it somehow like this (using some method opposite to `&` which gives common elements of 2 arrays):

```
a !& b  #=> doesn't work of course
```

Another way might be to add two arrays and find the unique element with some method similar to `uniq`, so that:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,4,4].some_method #=> would return 3
```

Comment: `(a-b) | (b-a) # => [3]` See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2D and note that it's not commutative, i.e. in general `a-b != b-a`

Comment: That should be: (a-b) | (b-a)

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci Right you are. I had even written it correctly in my test console, but rewrote it wrong.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: isn't that O(N ** 2) as well?

Comment: It depends on how Ruby implements it. Which is to say, I don't know. The arrays could also converted to [`Set`s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and then [`Set#^`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-5E) used, which since it uses hashes, _could_ be either O(n log n) or O(n).

Comment: Or sort the arrays (which should be O(n log n)), then iterate through the two, adding elements which are in only one array to a result array (O(n)).

Comment: @Jacka, I believe the answer by Chuck should be the accepted one. Can you change it so other people will find it more easily?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest (in terms of using only the arrays already in place and stock array methods, anyway) solution is the [union](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-7C) of the [differences](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2D):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,4]
(a-b) | (b-a)
=> [3]
```

This may or may not be better than `O(n**2)`. There are other options which are likely to give better peformance (see other answers/comments).

Edit: Here's a quick-ish implementation of the sort-and-iterate approach (this assumes no array has repeated elements; otherwise it will need to be modified depending on what behavior is wanted in that case). If anyone can come up with a shorter way to do it, I'd be interested. The limiting factor is the sort used. I assume Ruby uses some sort of Quicksort, so complexity averages `O(n log n)` with possible worst-case of `O(n**2)`; if the arrays are already sorted, then of course the two calls to `sort` can be removed and it will run in `O(n)`.

```
def diff a, b
  a = a.sort
  b = b.sort
  result = []
  bi = 0
  ai = 0
  while (ai < a.size && bi < b.size)
    if a[ai] == b[bi]
      ai += 1
      bi += 1
    elsif a[ai]<b[bi]
      result << a[ai]
      ai += 1
    else
      result << b[bi]
      bi += 1
    end
  end
  result += a[ai, a.size-ai] if ai<a.size
  result += b[bi, b.size-bi] if bi<b.size
  result
end
```

Comment: Union of the difference! Thanks for that! Using underscore:

`result = _.union(_.difference(a, b), _.difference(b, a));`

Answer (score 24):

As @iamnotmaynard noted in the comments, this is traditionally a set operation (called the symmetric difference). Ruby's Set class includes this operation, so the most idiomatic way to express it would be with a Set:

```
Set.new(a) ^ b
```

That should give O(n) performance (since a set membership test is constant-time).

Answer (score 11):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
a + b - (a & b)
# => [1, 4]
```

Comment: Which one is preferrable? This or the accepted solution?

Comment: this solution is better from garbage collection point of view (you can see less value for **total_allocated_object** with disabled GC).

Answer (score 1):

The solution for Array divergences is like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
(a - b) | (b - a)
# => [1, 4]
```

You can also read my blog post about [Array coherences](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/array-coherences)